# Drag disable on position fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to drag a div from another div which have a position fixed, but it is not working ! the drag is disabled. But when i change the position to another type (absolute, relative ..etc) the drag works fine .

CSS

```
.artefact {
width: 100px;
height : 100px; 
background-color: grey; 
position: relative;
}

        #zoneEchange7 {
    width: 20%;
        height: 9.2592%;
       /* position: fixed;*/
        bottom: 0;
        left: 70%;
        /*background-color: #6adcfa;*/
      }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="zoneEchange7" class="zoneEchange">
<div id="Artefact4" class="draggable artefact"> <p> Titre </p> </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
interact('.artefact')
  .draggable({
    inertia: true,
//l element reste dans sa zone limite , il peut pas sortir de son parent 
    restrict: {
     // restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },
    // activer autoScroll
    autoScroll: true,


//appeler cette fonction a chaque action de glissement 
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
//appeler cette fontion a chaque fin de l'action de glissement 
    onend: function (event) {

    }
  }
```

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried so far..

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enforced draggable() object to fixed position.
Try to add a high z-index to the fixed element.

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
```

Or

```
position: fixed !important;
```